# Best practices with \titlespacing?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, best-practices

I think my titles are too close to the text as they are set by default, but when I try to modify the distance, my document does not look nice. What are the best practices for `\titlespacing` options?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=4cm, bottom=3.7cm, left=5cm, right=3.5cm}   
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[bottom,norule]{footmisc}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1\baselineskip} 


\begin{document}

\newpage
\chapter{Literature Review}

\section{Historical Perspective on Dialect Studies of American English}

\subsection{Dialect Studies in the United States}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vehicula sem vel risus pharetra id viverra velit consectetur. Donec faucibus egestas eros. Nunc vel velit in risus tristique molestie. Cras at libero sem. Aenean sollicitudin, ipsum ut bibendum sollicitudin, lacus arcu malesuada risus, sollicitudin posuere tortor nulla quis metus. Aenean odio enim, dignissim id pellentesque quis, aliquam eu elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc rhoncus adipiscing pharetra. Integer hendrerit odio eget nisi bibendum et venenatis nisl cursus. Maecenas massa elit, facilisis placerat volutpat et, suscipit eget velit.

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. Nullam in eros non nunc tincidunt faucibus vitae et enim. Pellentesque luctus libero sit amet leo venenatis imperdiet. Quisque pretium, ante eu condimentum varius, felis velit tristique mauris, quis congue augue quam eu diam. Nulla facilisi.

Proin ligula lectus, volutpat eu suscipit id, gravida sit amet velit. Praesent ullamcorper orci eget metus gravida ut mattis erat dignissim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec et justo ac dui ultrices ornare. Duis quis leo quis diam gravida malesuada in ut tellus. In tincidunt sem in mi pellentesque mollis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris interdum pellentesque varius. Donec lacinia pulvinar risus, vitae posuere urna imperdiet eget. Phasellus ac neque arcu, nec laoreet lorem. Mauris nec sem id mauris vestibulum hendrerit. Etiam sapien purus, sodales in pretium lacinia, mollis vitae leo.

\subsection{Dialect Atlases} 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vehicula sem vel risus pharetra id viverra velit consectetur. Donec faucibus egestas eros. Nunc vel velit in risus tristique molestie. Cras at libero sem. Aenean sollicitudin, ipsum ut bibendum sollicitudin, lacus arcu malesuada risus, sollicitudin posuere tortor nulla quis metus. 

\subsubsection{Origins of Dialect Atlases}
Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. Nullam in eros non nunc tincidunt faucibus vitae et enim. Pellentesque luctus libero sit amet leo venenatis imperdiet. Quisque pretium, ante eu condimentum varius, felis velit tristique mauris, quis congue augue quam eu diam. Nulla facilisi.

Proin ligula lectus, volutpat eu suscipit id, gravida sit amet velit. Praesent ullamcorper orci eget metus gravida ut mattis erat dignissim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec et justo ac dui ultrices ornare. Duis quis leo quis diam gravida malesuada in ut tellus. In tincidunt sem in mi pellentesque mollis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris interdum pellentesque varius. Donec lacinia pulvinar risus, vitae posuere urna imperdiet eget. Phasellus ac neque arcu, nec laoreet lorem. Mauris nec sem id mauris vestibulum hendrerit. Etiam sapien purus, sodales in pretium lacinia, mollis vitae leo.

Proin ligula lectus, volutpat eu suscipit id, gravida sit amet velit. Praesent ullamcorper orci eget metus gravida ut mattis erat dignissim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec et justo ac dui ultrices ornare. Duis quis leo quis diam gravida malesuada in ut tellus. In tincidunt sem in mi pellentesque mollis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris interdum pellentesque varius. Donec lacinia pulvinar risus, vitae posuere urna imperdiet eget. Phasellus ac neque arcu, nec laoreet lorem. Mauris nec sem id mauris vestibulum hendrerit. Etiam sapien purus, sodales in pretium lacinia, mollis vitae leo.

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. Nullam in eros non nunc tincidunt faucibus vitae et enim. Pellentesque luctus libero sit amet leo venenatis imperdiet. Quisque pretium, ante eu condimentum varius, felis velit tristique mauris, quis congue augue quam eu diam. Nulla facilisi.
Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. Nullam in eros non nunc tincidunt faucibus vitae et enim. Pellentesque luctus libero sit amet leo venenatis imperdiet. Quisque pretium, ante eu condimentum varius, felis velit tristique mauris, quis congue augue quam eu diam. Nulla facilisi.

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. Nullam in eros non nunc tincidunt faucibus vitae et enim. Pellentesque luctus libero sit amet leo venenatis imperdiet. Quisque pretium, ante eu condimentum varius, felis velit tristique mauris, quis congue augue quam eu diam. Nulla facilisi.

\subsubsection{The \emph{Linguistic Atlas of the United States and Canada}}

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. 

\paragraph{The \emph{Linguistic Atlas of New England}}
Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. Nullam in eros non nunc tincidunt faucibus vitae et enim. Pellentesque luctus libero sit amet leo venenatis imperdiet. Quisque pretium, ante eu condimentum varius, felis velit tristique mauris, quis congue augue quam eu diam. Nulla facilisi.
Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. Nullam in eros non nunc tincidunt faucibus vitae et enim. Pellentesque luctus libero sit amet leo venenatis imperdiet. Quisque pretium, ante eu condimentum varius, felis velit tristique mauris, quis congue augue quam eu diam. Nulla facilisi.

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. 

\paragraph{Developments of the Surveys for \emph{LAUSC} after the Publication of \emph{LANE}}\label{Developments}
Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. 
Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. 

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. 

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. 

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. 

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. 

Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. Sed luctus volutpat mi, vel rhoncus lacus semper quis. Pellentesque egestas lobortis mollis. Quisque egestas, velit sed cursus venenatis, lacus felis vehicula ligula, et elementum mauris dolor pellentesque sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ullamcorper congue leo fermentum cursus. Curabitur tempor vulputate magna eu imperdiet. Pellentesque ornare metus ac odio pretium auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras quis neque sit amet tortor scelerisque cursus condimentum vitae massa. 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add a MWE so we can see how your title and text look like in your set up. You know, what you find not nice, maybe I find delicate and nice. _Nice_ is subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I compiled the document, and found the space between headings pleasant (that is my opinion). I don't know if the margins is a requirement from your university or publisher, but having a top margin bigger than bottom margin brakes all typographical recommendations I have read (Bringhurst, `memoir`manual, `KOMAscript` manual, different Scandinavian authors). Normally, the recommendation is to have a bottom margin approximately twice as big as the top margin.

The same goes for right and left margins. When you are using `oneside`, the left and right margin shall normally be equal, save for any gutter (binding
correction) you need for binding (normally 8 mm to 12 mm, depending om number of sheets, if you glue bind it). But if you glue bind the document, you shall consider to use `twoside`. Then the two inner margin put together shall be approximately the same as the outer margins.  If you hole punch the document to put it in a binder, you do not need a gutter, and you can use `oneside`.

Using `geometry` (and `typearea`), you also have to decide if the header and footer shall be part of the text block. If your running header or footer contains the page number *only*, do not include them. In addition, I recommend using `heightrounded=true`. So I recommend changing the `geometry` set up line to read:

```
\geometry{heightrounded=true, top=2cm, bottom=4cm, left=4.25cm, right=4.25cm}
```

I recommend you to read the first part of the `memoir` manual. It has a lot of recommendations for setting up a pleasant page layout.

To avoid tinkering with margin and typeblock, consider using the package `typearea` from the `KOMAscript`-bundle. It will calculate nice type blocks and margin automatically. In your MWE, try replacing

```
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{includefoot=false, heightrounded=true, top=2cm, bottom=4cm, left=5cm, right=3.5cm}
```

with `typearea` (see command below). Also, consider load the `microtype`-package, to get even better typography. So, in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[letterspace=100,babel=true,tracking=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[DIV=9]{typearea}
```

In my opinion, this is a good compromise when you are using A4 paper.

When I recommended reading the `memoir` manual, I was referring to the first part, where the author writes about layout. Implementing his theories in `memoir` (using `memoir` internal commands), is another story.

Comment: @Seinung: I am reading the memoir manual as you suggested. Could you guide me through it, though? It's dense and it uses US measures, so it's hard to get through it safely. What I do understand that I need an average of 66 characters in a line, so I made my left/right margins even smaller than what you suggest (left=4.80cm, right=4.70cm). My font is 11pt, I have been told from some LaTeX users that 12pt is children size. Also, I have no double spacing pretty much for the same reason.

Comment: I also tried the package typearea, but it sets very small margins.

Comment: @Costi I have updated  my answer.

Comment: This microtype does miracles!

Comment: I don't understand the typearea command. What about this (preamble to be substituted in my MWE above):

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{includefoot=false, heightrounded=true, top=5.8cm, bottom=6.5cm, left=4.7cm, right=4.7cm} 
\usepackage[letterspace=100,babel=true,tracking=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[bottom,norule]{footmisc}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1\baselineskip}

Comment: @Costi In my opinion, the type block is too small with your setting. You get only 37 lines of text. Decrease the top margin to 3.25cm, and you can also have smaller left and right margins. I think `\usepackage[DIV8]{typearea}` is a good compromise, it gives 40 lines of text. Normally I use 42 or 45 lines and a typeblock 1.618 times the length of the line, with 11pt MinionPro. The problem is the format of the A4 paper. It is impossible ty find nice typeblocks with OK line lenghts. You have to make some compromises, or trim the paper.